# Eta Squared / Partial Eta Squared Using R

Tags: r, anova

I've ran an ANOVA for a 2X2 mixed study design comparing the test results of a memory test, within and between a group of students. The code I used was as follows:

```
    results <- ezANOVA(data = scores, 
               dv = PercentCorrect, 
               wid = Participant,
               between = Language,
               within = Condition,
               type = 3, 
               detailed = TRUE, 
               return_aov = TRUE)
               print(results)
```

My question is, how do I find the partial ETA for each effect. Also, I'm struggling to identify which effect relates to which IV in my results. My results show INTERCEPT IV1 IV2 IV:IV2. How do I know which is the results for the in-between and within group comparisons? I'm using R and have looked at many a youtube video but I'm completely stuck! Thanks in advance Stack community!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the package/function `heplots::etasq()`.

Also, you can look over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17961349/r-partial-eta-squared-for-repeated-measures-anova-car-package) for similar question on a 2x3 repeated measures.